# React native 0.59 warning: PerformanceLogger: Attempting to start a timespan that already exists

Tags: react-native

After upgrading to 0.59 (we are currently at v0.59.5) we started getting these warnings:

```
'PerformanceLogger: Attempting to end a timespan that has already ended ', 'renderApplication_React_render'
```

and

```
'PerformanceLogger: Attempting to start a timespan that already exists ', 'renderApplication_React_render'
```

Anyone seeing the same or knows how to fix it?

Comment: do you use react-native-navigation (wix) ?

Comment: We don't use react-native-navigation

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you don't use react-native-navigation, but do you use react-navigation?

I was getting this message in the console when following a deep link into my app.

The issue was that I had forgotten to set `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I had an event listener in `componentDidMount` on my navigator subscribed to `didFocus`, but the callback for the listener wasn't firing and I was only getting those warnings in the console.

Comment: We use react-navigation and this is happening on iOS, not sure why.

Comment: Does it happen when you deep link into the app?

Comment: It happens by just entering and exiting the app (we integrated react native into an existing app and has several entry points). The info log is not shown on screen but is inside the debug console.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what it could be. I didn't experience the issue on iOS, but maybe there is a similar property to Android's `launchMode` in the plist or somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For android, add
`android:launchMode="singleTask"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For iOS, comment out the following in `RNNBridgeModule.m`:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getConstants:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    resolve([Constants getConstants]);
}
```

More on [launchMode](https://medium.com/@iammert/android-launchmode-visualized-8843fc833dbe), must read.